# Parser PHP xmlreader вывести все элементы

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Помогите плз!
В общем написал парсер.
Надо модифицировать код так, чтобы все элементы $xml->type->attributes()->name; выводились, а не один...

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<zoomby>
<types>
    <type name_lat="auto" name="Авто" id="20"/>
    <type name_lat="analytics" name="Аналитика" id="40"/>
    <type name_lat="animation" name="Анимация" id="31"/>
    <type name_lat="anime" name="Аниме" id="53"/>
    <type name_lat="arthouse" name="Арт-хаус" id="17"/>
    <type name_lat="basketball" name="Баскетбол" id="44"/>
    <type name_lat="biathlon" name="Биатлон" id="47"/>
    <type name_lat="action" name="Боевик" id="1"/>
</types>
</zoomby>
```

И есть PHP

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('cont.xml');

while ($reader->read()) {

    switch ($reader->nodeType) {


        case (XMLReader::ELEMENT):
            // если находим в xml элемент <types> начинаем обрабатывать его
            if ($reader->localName == 'types') {

                $item = $reader->expand();
                $dom = new DomDocument();
                $node = $dom->importNode($item, true);
                $dom->appendChild($node);
                // загружаем в simpleXML только текущий node
                $xml = simplexml_import_dom($node);

                echo $xml->type->attributes()->name;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$xml->type->attributes()` возвращает класс [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.simplexmlelement.php), который реализует интерфейс Traversable. Так что можно пройтись по атрибутам в цикле:

Строчку:

```
echo $xml->type->attributes()->name;
```

Заменить на:

```
foreach($xml->type->attributes() as $attribute) {
   echo $attribute->getName() . ' : ' . $attribute . PHP_EOL;
}
```

В результате получится такой вывод:

> name_lat : auto
>
> name : Авто
>
> id : 20